# Help troubleshooting Mosfets in Switching Circuit

Tags: transistors, mosfet, ltspice, simulation

I've been trying to design a simple circuit to switch between two Supply rails (3.3V_SW & Vbat) while giving one of them a higher priority (3.3V_SW). The circuit in simulation is showing to be not working well as shown below.
[image]
[image]

As shown above the toggling between VBAT (3.6V) &  3.3V_SW (3.3V) is unsuccessful , the transition from 3.6V goes down to 2.4V instead of 3.3V.

And I've built the circuit in person and the operation goes as follow, When the VBAT is activated the output is 3.6V (good) , when the 3.3V_SW is activated the output is 3.3V (good) . Now the problem starts when 3.3V_SW is deactivated the output is 3.3V instead of 3.6V coming from VBAT.

Would definitely appreciate it if anyone would share their insights on what might be the solution to make this circuit work as intended.

Comment: Have you probed the output of your PWL function? I don’t think it’s set up the way you intended it to…

Answer (score 0):

If you can tolerate a diode drop:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqGXxp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or, what you probably want:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu4cEP.png)</sup>

This might be hard to do with MOSFETS at such low operating voltages.

Comment: These circuits are still just as problematic as the original: They allow reverse current from OUT to VSW, causing the voltage on VSW to never drop when the power supply is disconnected. That, in turn, makes OP's circuit believe that a power supply is connected permanently, so that it never switches over to VBAT. The same happens in the BJT circuit. (The single-diode variant will just inject a bunch of current from the battery into the 3.3V supply when the lithium battery is fully charged, raising it to potentially up to 4V if there's not much load and a Schottky is used.)

Comment: @JonathanS. my second circuit does not allow reverse current when the transistors are off (ok, maybe nanoamps of leakage that can be managed). They are logically OR'd, and their priority can be independently controlled via the inputs. Only 0.2V lost for  E-C junction which seems like a reasonable compromise. MOSFETs could be used if you can find a low enough Vgs(th) that is suitable, especially as high-side fets.

Comment: The off-state itself isn't the issue, it's detecting the off-state that's difficult. If Q2 is active (in the BJT schematic) and the voltage source is removed from VSW, OUT will instead provide power to VSW. As a result, no matter whether VSW is externally powered or not, it always has voltage and will always be read as "powered" - at least until the voltage on OUT has collapsed and the downstream circuitry shut down. This is why OP's prototype circuit failed to switch.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that MOSFETs conduct in both directions when they're on.

Let's assume both voltages are present. Q5 (battery -> output) is off and Q6 (+3.3V -> output) is on, as you intended. Now you turn off the +3.3V rail. Q6 is still on because current flows through it in reverse, keeping the +3.3V rail up, which in turn keeps Q6 on. At the same time, while Q5 is off, current can flow through its body diode. The circuit latches in the +3.3V state and can never leave it.

Such a setup is never going to work as long as you try to do the switching via pure voltage sensing because voltage can back-feed from the output to the input, keeping the input voltage high even when the voltage source is disconnected.

The easiest solution that I can think of is to boost the 3.3V rail to something like 5V, and then use an ideal diode OR controller (i.e. the LM66200), or just a pair of plain Schottky diodes. This of course assumes that downstream circuitry can operate on 5V.